# trigger path filter not automating the pipeline

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, triggers, path, azure-pipelines

[image]

I have a Single repository which contains 1 solution file for all API's and Function Apps. I have created separate pipelines for all API's and Function apps.  If there is any change in one of the API's or function apps that particular pipeline has to be triggered. But for me all pipelines are triggering. So I have added trigger filtering path to the pipeline. But automatic triggering is not happening after adding trigger path filter.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the files directory structure in the repo?

Comment: i have added image of our file directory structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The include path should be path instead of others, for example:

My repo structure:

[image]

And now, I Specify the file `test.java` as the trigger path. My YAML build trigger configuration:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - com/Test/test.java
```

Result:

[image]